# Ip to hexa formatting

Tags: perl

i need to convert decimal ip to hexa value.
example:110.1.1.3 to 6e01:103.

But by using below code i am getting it in 6e01103. I need it either 6e01:103 or 6e:01:103 format. And then need to concatenate with hexa value 64:ff9b::, my end output needd to be 64:ff9b::6e01:103. Kindly help me in this.

```
sub ip_hexa($){
my $ip = shift;
my @octets = split /\./, $ip;
my $result; 
foreach (@octets){
$hexa_ip = join":",printf("%02x", "$_");
} 
return $hexa_ip;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely certain about the output you want, but there are a few issues with the code which I'll list below:

1. The `$` in the function declaration is not required. It sets the function's *prototype* which most likely does not do what you think it does. See [`perlsub`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes) for details.
2. `$hexa_ip` should be declared before being used as good practice to prevent hard to find errors. Perhaps you meant `my $hexa_ip` instead of `my $result`? In any case, use [`use strict`](http://perlmaven.com/strict) at the start of the program to catch such errors.
3. `printf()` prints to screen and only returns a boolean. Look at [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) for the right function to use.
4. `join()` is not being used correctly. See [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html).

Comment: Whilst your points are right, that still doesn't return the desired result - this returns `6e:01:01:03` (Not that I'm entirely sure what the OP is actually looking for, results wise).

Comment: @Sobrique you're right, thanks. It was not completely clear what the OP needs from the question and I made some assumptions so I've removed the code now.

Answer (score 0):

```
# 6e01:103
sprintf "%x:%x",
   unpack 'nn',
      pack 'C4',
         split /\./,
            '110.1.1.3'
```

```
# 6e:01:103
sprintf "%x:%x:%x",
   unpack 'CCn',
      pack 'C4',
         split /\./,
            '110.1.1.3'
```

The `sprintf` lines can be replaced with `join ':', map sprintf '%x',`

Comment: I fixed a bug in my answer.